# Obtain a barplot from boolean values?

Tags: pandas, list, python-2.7, dataframe, seaborn

I'm facing a bit of a problem. This is my dataframe:

```
Students     Subject       Mark
1            M F           7 4 3 7
2            I             5 6 
3            M F I S       2 3 0 
4            M             2 2 
5            F M I         5 1
6            I M F         6 2 3
7            I M           7
```

I want to plot a barplot with four "bars", for students respecting the next four conditions:

- Have 3 ore more letters in the column "Subject"
- Have at least one 3 in the colum "Marks"
- Have both things
- Have neither things

At first I was stuck, but I was suggested to proceed this way:

```
df["Subject"].str.count("\w+") >= 3

df["Mark"].str.count("3") >= 1

(df["Subject"].str.count("\w+") >= 3) & (df["Mark"].str.count("3") >= 1)
```

What I obtain are three boolean columns, but I don't know how to go from here to plot the barplot.
I was thinking about counting the values in each column, but I don't seem to find a way to do so, since it looks like I can't apply `value_counts()` to the boolean columns.

If you have any idea, please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need create DataFrame with all 4 masks, then count `True`s by `sum` and last plot:

```
m1 = df["Subject"].str.count("\w+") >= 3
m2 = df["Mark"].str.count("3") >= 1

df1 = pd.concat([m1, m2, m1 & m2, ~m1 & ~m2], axis=1, keys=('a','b','c','d'))

out = df1.sum()
```

If need seaborn solution:

```
import seaborn as sns

ax = sns.barplot(x="index", y="val", data=out.reset_index(name='val'))
```

For pandas (matplotlib) solution:

```
out.plot.bar()
```